# How to fix Request-URI Too Large error in rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, search

Im having an error that says:

> Request-URI Too Large

Actually I'm trying to add a search function on my experimental rails 3 app which accepts a `string` and a `date` as search parameters. For some reasons when I click the submit button to do the search the URL in my browser is very long and Im having this error I mentioned above.

Here is the code for my model **`trap.rb`**:

```
class Trap < ActiveRecord::Base

 def self.search(empcode, date_entry)
  if empcode and date_entry
   where('empcode LIKE ? and date_entry = ?', "%#{empcode}%", "#{date_entry}")
  else
   scoped
  end
 end
end
```

In the controller **`traps_controller.rb`**:

```
class TrapsController < ApplicationController

 def index
  @traps = Trap.search(params[:search_empcode], params[:search_date_entry])

  respond_to do |format|
   format.html # index.html.erb
   format.xml  { render :xml => @traps }
  end
 end

 .
 .
 .
end
```

And in the view **`index.html.erb`**:

```
<h2>TRAP 1.0</h2>

<%= form_tag traps_path, :method => 'get' do  %>
 <p>
  Employee Code: <%= text_field_tag :search_empcode, params[:search_empcode] %>
  Date Entry: <%= date_select :search_date_entry, params[:search_date_entry] %>
 </p>

 <p class="buttons"> <%= submit_tag "Search", :name => nil %></p>
<% end %>

<table>
 <tr>
  <th>Empcode</th>
  <th>Date entry</th>
  <th></th>
  <th></th>
  <th></th>
 </tr>

 <% @traps.each do |trap| %>
 <tr>
  <td><%= trap.empcode %></td>
  <td><%= trap.date_entry %></td>
  <td><%= link_to 'Show', trap %></td>
  <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_trap_path(trap) %></td>
  <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', trap, :confirm => 'Are you sure?', :method => :delete %></td>
 </tr>
 <% end %>
</table>

<br />

<%= link_to 'New Trap', new_trap_path %>
```

Can somebody tell me what's wrong with this one? If you know some alternatives. Pls help...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had this error authenticating against google's openID actually, they redirected me back to my own app with a few hundred GET params.  I didn't figure out what the issue was, but instead of using the built in Rails server, I started using thin instead and the error magically disappeared. Must just be the way the server handles them internally.

Try `gem install thin` then `thin start` from your rails root directory.

Comment: Do you hav any info on why this 'thin' stuff would work on this case?

Comment: I'm guessing from the answer below mine that webrick can't (without modifications) handle a url that large.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to keep using webbrick just go to lines 246 and 247 in `ruby-version/lib/ruby/version/webrick/httprequest.rb` and change the bytesize numbers, I just doubled them:

```
@request_line = read_line(socket, 2048) if socket
if @request_line.bytesize >= 2048 and @request_line[-1, 1] != LF
```